# Determine if Joomla is in a subdirectory

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Joomla 3.2.3

Hi all, I am trying to develop a plugin for Joomla (just for myself) and I have run into a problem.

Basically, the plugin searches for the URL linking to the local copy of bootstrap.min.css which is:

```
/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

This is then replaced by a CDN version of the Bootstrap CSS.

Everything works fine when the website is located in the root of the domain but if the website is in a subdirectory then the link changes to:

```
/subdirectory/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

And the plugin stops loading the CDN version.

Is there a PHP based way to determine if the website is being hosted in a subdirectory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted this by using

```
JURI::base(true);
```

As outlined at http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/base

Answer (score 0):

the constant JPATH_BASE gives the base directory Joomla is installed in:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_find_your_absolute_path

This points to the directory the index.php is located in. Which parses all requests to the joomla installation.

Comment: That page seems to be for Joomla 1.0 and 1.5, would this still apply to Joomla 3.x?

Comment: @DesignSubway - yes, `JPATH_BASE` is still part of Joomla 3.x ;)